# Sprite-kit game performance

Tags: performance, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I'm making a Sprite kit game. There I have a button, which have to be hidden, while some condition won't be true. So I add this button to the scene and make it hidden. So which way is better ones? To make a button, add it to the scene and make it hidden? Or add it to the scene, when I need it?

Comment: That depends on your needs. Do you need it to constantly be hidden then reappearing? Or do you only need it to appear once?

Comment: When node is hidden it is just not rendered. Still, the node can interact in different ways with other nodes...You can even run an action on a hidden node. One button, like in your case, can hardly make a difference in performance no matter what, but having like 200+ nodes on screen would be another story and choosing between pooling (eg. creating nodes once and toggling hidden property) vs re-creating nodes over and over again, could make different results (pooling would be performant way to go).

Answer (score 5):

If you do not plan on using the button a lot, then do not add it.  We do not know for certain what optimizations get done on hidden objects, so it is possible that it will still be a part of the drawing process and just skipped.  If you find yourself needing to flash the button on and off in rapid session, then you would want to add it to the scene and use the hidden property.  Now the performance loss is minimal, so also consider your time in the matter.  Is it going to be more work for you to do add/remove, or is it the same as hidden?  Take things like this into consideration.

Comment: This is solid advice.  I'd also add that a lot of this will depend on whether you're using the SpriteKit scene editor to build your scenes.  If you're laying out your scenes there, it's generally a lot easier to put in the stuff you'll need and cull things you don't than generate them with code.  That way, you can lay out those elements in a visual manner like your other items.  This also allows you to easily attach animations to them, creating the animations with the GUI that has nice preview affordances.